# Using drools compute duration of events within a text log

Tags: drools

We're experimenting with Drools to process a large amount of textual data from log files.  I'm trying to understand how to properly measure an event time.

The event in question begins in one log line, but may finish either by a successful completion or an unusual abort.  That's what I'm having problems capturing.  Here's how the log entries might look (when the other log lines are filtered out):

```
Jan 24 06:50:29 app[623]:  CallOriginateCmd
Jan 24 07:19:27 app[616]:  Client ended the call 
Jan 24 09:00:18 app[623]:  CallOriginateCmd
Jan 24 09:34:48 app[616]:  Client ended the call 
Jan 24 11:03:56 app[623]:  CallOriginateCmd
Jan 24 12:56:58 app[616]:  Client ended the call 
Jan 24 15:48:11 app[623]:  CallOriginateCmd
Jan 24 16:13:24 app[616]:  Client ended the call 
Jan 24 17:16:16 app[623]:  CallOriginateCmd
Jan 24 18:48:51 app[616]:  Client ended the call 
Jan 25 06:09:01 app[623]:  CallOriginateCmd
Jan 25 06:09:24 app[623]:  Failure: timeout sending Config 
Jan 25 06:09:26 app[623]:  CallOriginateCmd
Jan 25 06:09:50 app[623]:  Failure: timeout sending Config
```

I'm trying to create rules which links the Jan 24 06:50:29 call with the 07:19:27 termination, the Jan 25 06:09:01 call with the 06:09:24 failure, etc.  My rules below do not create a Call() object with the right start/end times that I would like.

Here's the outline of my code:

```
rule "Found Call Start"
    when
        LogEntry( message matches ".*CallOriginateCmd.*", logTimestamp : timestamp )
    then
        Call call = new Call();
        call.setStarttime( logTimestamp );
        call.setPartial ( true );
        insert( call );
        AnalysisLog.debug( logTimestamp, "Call Started" );
end

rule "Found Call End"
    when
        LogEntry( message matches ".*Client ended the call.*", logTimestamp : timestamp )
        call : Call( partial == true )
    then
        call.setEndtime( logTimestamp );
        call.setPartial( false );
        call.setFailure( false );
        update( call );
        AnalysisLog.debug( logTimestamp, "Call Ended." );
end

rule "Found Call Failure"
    when 
        LogEntry( message matches ".*timeout sending Config.*", logTimestamp : timestamp )
        call : Call( partial == true )
    then
        call.setEndtime( logTimestamp );
        call.setPartial( false );
        call.setFailure( true );
        update( call );
        AnalysisLog.debug( logTimestamp, "Call Failed." );
end
```

The output from above is:

```
Jan 17 22:53:04: Call Started
Jan 18 02:10:23: Call Failed.
Jan 17 23:09:23: Call Started
Jan 18 02:10:23: Call Failed.
Jan 17 23:25:39: Call Started
```

Every call seems to match Failed, although only the last call in the log should have matched.

I thought that the code:

```
call : Call( partial == true )
```

within the "when" clause would link the start+end or start+abort together, but this apparently doesn't do this.

Instead, I suppose I need to find a way in the "when" clause to find the call where the logTimestamp is closest to the Starttime of the call.  Is this possible?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing any correlation fields in your log, so I a assuming that the messages are always sequential? i.e., a message starts a call and the next message either completes or fails the call. If that is the case, there are many ways of doing it, but you can try something like this:

```
rule "Found Call End"
    when
        $s : LogEntry( message matches ".*CallOriginateCmd.*" )
        $e : LogEntry( message matches ".*Client ended the call.*" )
        not LogEntry( timestamp > $s.timestamp && timestamp < $e.timestamp )
    then
        Call call = new Call();
        call.setStarttime( $s.getTimestamp() );
        call.setEndtime( $e.getTimestamp() );
        call.setFailure( false );
        retract( $s );
        retract( $e );
        insert( call );
        AnalysisLog.debug( logTimestamp, "Call Ended." );
end
```

Write a similar rule for your call failed scenario. If there are correlation fields in your log, just add constraints to correlate the correct LogEntries.

Comment: That did it, thanks!  I didn't think to add both LogEntry's to the when clause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Drools Fusion, you will be able to deal with LogEntry as events, allowing you to use temporal operators to check that the start call event happens before the end call event. Drools fusion will also provide you an automatic event lifecycle management. I'm still trying to understand what is your main objective, beyond the technical issues.
Cheers

Comment: Updated description to include more detailed info.  Is it clearer now?